# RecyclerView Grid animation - Strange overlay effect

Tags: android, grid, android-recyclerview

I use RecyclerView to create a grid with focus item being scale up. However, I have a problem to load the focused item when the effect is strange. I add screenshot below.

Here is my code to handle scale up affect:

```
public static synchronized void animateScaleUp(View v) {
    float currentScaleX = v.getScaleX();
    float currentScaleY = v.getScaleY();
    float targetScale = 1.2f;
    PropertyValuesHolder scaleXHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, currentScaleX, targetScale);
    PropertyValuesHolder scaleYHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, currentScaleY, targetScale);
    ValueAnimator scaleAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v, scaleXHolder, scaleYHolder);
    scaleAnimator.start();
}
```

[image: Bug RecyclerView with focus scale]

Comment: You need to also increase the elevation of the card along with scaling

Comment: @Bhargav: I did put card_view:cardElevation attributes in xml file. The shadow works fine but the right and bottom items are overlay to current item.

Comment: yes you need to increase the elevation of the card that you touched so that it goes on top of other cards surrouding it

Comment: @Bhargav: I did increase the holder.cardView.setCardElevation(20); compare to original card_view:cardElevation="6dp" of cardview. However, it's not working.

Comment: any one please help me :(